# How to make Emacs check my email and report new mail

Tags: gnus, email

I'm using GNUS to read my emails. Is there some way to make it automatically
check my mail box and report new mails somehow? Maybe some package exists to
do this sort of thing?

Comment: The idea of Emacs is that you modify it to your wishes. Asking for packages to modify it, seems counter-intuitively to me. I would suggest that you could learn some Lisp, to check if there are new mails.

Comment: @ReneFroger, heh, well, thanks for your advice, but I know Lisp for years now, I did a lot of Common Lisp and Emacs Lisp in the past, and I've written various Common Lisp libraries and bindings, several Emacs Lisp packages, check my my profile, you may find some of them useful. As for this issue, of course I can write whatever I like, but this won't happen if there is something that is already working, I've other things to do right now.

Comment: Excuse me for my poor advice. I checked your profile, and I'm very sorry for my harsh words. I'm even using one of your packages..

Comment: @ReneFroger, nevermind... Note that even while Emacs let you modify everything you like, we shouldn't reinvent the wheel, so it seems practical to ask if some useful thing is already implemented. When you are not satisfied with existing solutions or you want something special, then yes, go ahead and write some Emacs Lisp! :-D

Comment: [Zawinski's law of software envelopment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski#Zawinski.27s_law_of_software_envelopment) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to look at [Gnus Demon](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Daemons.html).

From `gnus-demon.el` you'll probably want `gnus-demon-scan-mail` or `gnus-demon-add-scanmail` [Defaults to 120, 60: Scan every 2 hours if idle for 1 hour].

This is probably closer to the standard 5-minute scan on phones/applications:

```
(gnus-demon-add-handler 'gnus-demon-scan-mail 5 t)
```

EmacsWiki has a comparison of [Gnus Notifications](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusNotificationComparison), some are for modeline alerts to new email, some are for desktop notifications.